# Center scrollview vertically when few elements and fill parent when many

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

I want a layout to be centered vertically when there are few elements in it, see the image to the left. When there are many elements, I want it to grow and become a scroll view that covers the whole screen. See right image.

How can I achieve this?

[image]

The red elements are dynamically added to the layout. The two blue TextViews are outside the scrollview. Basically the scrollview kicks in when we have no more space left on the screen.

Comment: I would suggest you to use listview with header and footer inside a linearlayout with gravity=center_vertical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#fff">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Top TextView"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

    <!-- You can remove min Height if you don't want it-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00ffff"
        android:minHeight="100dp">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <!-- Do you Code here.-->

        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Bottom TextView"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you Andy! This was pretty much what I was looking for. However, I had to change the LinearLayout containing the ScrollView to have layout_width=0 and layout_weight=1.